# how to access a directory in c and open the files in c in visual studio using findfirstfile etc

Tags: c, visual-studio, directory

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
        HANDLE hFind;
    FILE *inputFile;

    int i;
    char path[MAX_PATH];
    strcpy(path, "C:\\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\files");
    hFind = FindFirstFile((LPCWSTR)path , &FindFileData);
    WCHAR *fileName = FindFileData.cFileName;

    fopen_s(&inputFile, (const char *)fileName, "rb");

    Init();

    checkFile(inputFile);
    fclose(inputFile);



    }
```

I just want access all the files in the directory 'files' and open it and do the necessary operations on the file. The directory may contain many files of different extentions.PLEASE HELP! i am stuck. I realize i need to use FINDNEXTFILE as well but i dont know how.!!
please help.
accessing from command window is also an option but i dont know that as well.i am new to c programming! thanks

Comment: Google is your friend :) This site pretty much gives you the answer. http://cboard.cprogramming.com/windows-programming/83267-msdn-example-code-findfirstfile-findnextfile.html

Comment: but this just prints the name. I need the file to run the operations on it

Comment: Have you seen `FindNextFile()` in the linked code and checked what it returns in param 2? It's exactly the same as you get from `FindFirstFile()`

Comment: Your problem statement said, *"I realize I need to use FINDNEXTFILE as well but I dont know how.!!"*. My link was in answer to that problem.